# Chaining Redux actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am new to React, Redux and JS overall. I want to know how can I dispatch and action after another is finished - Promises in correct way. My code actually works but it keeps throwing error:

```
readingActions.js?14b9:56 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch(...).then is not a function(…)
```

This is my setup.

- This is my action creator what I want chained action and where warning happends.

  ```
  export function createReading(reading) {
    return function (dispatch) {
      dispatch({type: CREATE_READING});
      return request(
        `${API_URL}new`, {method: 'POST', body:JSON.stringify(reading)},
        (json) => {( dispatch({type: CREATE_READING_SUCCESS, res: json}).then(dispatch(Notifications.success(showSuccess(json.book.title)))))},
        (json) => { dispatch({type: CREATE_READING_ERROR400, res: json}).then(dispatch(Notifications.error(showError(json.error)))) },
        (res) => { dispatch({type: CREATE_READING_ERROR500, res: res}) },
        (ex) => { dispatch({type: CREATE_READING_FAILURE, error: ex}) },
      )
    }
  }
  ```

As you can see the problem is in .then, since I dont know how to trigger action correctly.

- You can also see request that is my helper function that looks like so (here I append token, return different responses):

  ```
  export function request(url, options, success, error400, error, failure) {
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")
      headers.append("Accept", "application/json")
      options["headers"] = headers;

       if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
          let token = localStorage.jwtToken;
          headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT '+token);
       }

      return fetch(url, options)
          .then(res => {
              if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
                  res.json().then(json => {
                       return success(json)
                  })
              } else if (res.status === 400) {
                  res.json().then(json => {
                      return error400(json)
                  })
              } else {
                  return error(res)
              }
          }).catch((ex) => {
              return failure(ex)
          })
  }
  ```

Question is how can I execute proper .then and what would be the correct way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to dispatch actions in chains you can actually implement it on your own.

Now say after analysing a bit  you take a pen and paper and start write basic algorithm for how it should work and you come up with following:-

`dispatch(action) => action returns function => action returns function => action returns an object(here you chain ends)`

Now from above if you see that you create a middleware and keep on dispatching actions which return functions until you get an action with returns an object. This is what [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) does.

So even if you try to create something of your own do that for your learning, but eventually you will come up with something like thunk or maybe some other package.

I would really say give [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) a try.Also for middleware understanding I would recommend you can check [redux middleware docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html).